# Parse XML android

Tags: android, xml, android-xmlpullparser

I am having difficulties in parsing XML in android. i have the following XML

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" to="blob@faisal-system/68bb97e7">
  <album xmlns="naseebalbum">
    <albumpicture>
      <title>day1</title>
      <creationdate>1397502000000</creationdate>
      <picture>BASE64EncodedStringOfImage</picture>
    </albumpicture>
    <comments>
      <comment>
        <commentid>1</commentid>
        <username>sana</username>
        <text>i loved that pic</text>
        <commenttime>1398264140000</commenttime>
      </comment>
    </comments>
    <likes>
      <like>
        <likeid>4</likeid>
        <username>sana</username>
        <liketime>1398250919000</liketime>
      </like>
    </likes>
  </album>
</iq>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

I want to get data from Likes tag comments tag title tag and picture tag.

**Heres what i have been trying to do.**

```
public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        payload=""+parser.getText();

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0) {

                switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    if (depth > 0) {
                        sb.append("</" + parser.getName() + ">");
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    StringBuilder attrs = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < parser.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
                        attrs.append(parser.getAttributeName(i) + "=\""
                                + parser.getAttributeValue(i) + "\" ");
                    }
                    sb.append("<" + parser.getName() + " " + attrs.toString() + ">");

                    break;
                default:
                    sb.append(parser.getText());
                    break;
                }
            }
            payload = sb.toString();

        iq=new CustomIQ(payload);
        iq.setType(Type.RESULT);

        return iq;
    }
```

Comment: did you check my post? working?

Comment: Yes i checked it.. it was very helpful, +1 but it could'nt help me solve my problem completely.

Comment: does it work for you is the question?

Comment: actually, i have stopped working on the parsing thing right now, will get back on parsing in a couple of days then i will apply your method completely, than we will see if it is working completely or not.

Comment: no hurry take your time

Comment: oh i remember, i could'nt figure out.. what is InputStream here? do i have to convert the xml into input stream? as i am using xmpp not normal webservices, i get the xml into a String.

Comment: where do you get xml from? yes you need to convert it into inputStream

Comment: i tried it, but i checked it while debugging that my program goes to the catch block.. i get some kind of exception there..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53873/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hassaan-rabbani)

Comment: @post stacktrace. that is a working example.

Answer (score 1):

To parse

```
 public Void parse(InputStream is) {
       try
       {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(is, null);

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "iq");
        while (xpp.nextTag() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "album");
            xpp.nextTag();

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "albumpicture");
            xpp.nextTag();

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "title");
            Log.i("title is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "title");
            xpp.nextTag();


            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "creationdate");
            Log.i("creation date i....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "creationdate");
            xpp.nextTag();

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "picture");
            Log.i("picture is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "picture");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "albumpicture");
            xpp.nextTag();

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "comments");
            xpp.nextTag();


            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "comment");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "commentid");
            Log.i("comment id is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "commentid");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "username");
            Log.i("username is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "username");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "text");
            Log.i("text is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "text");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "commenttime");
            Log.i("comment is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "commenttime");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "comment");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "comments");
            xpp.nextTag();

            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "likes");
            xpp.nextTag();


            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "like");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "likeid");
            Log.i("like id is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "likeid");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "username");
            Log.i("username is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "username");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "liketime");
            Log.i("liketime is....",""+xpp.nextText());
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "liketime");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "like");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "likes");

            xpp.nextTag();
            xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "album");

        }
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "iq");
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return null;

    }
```

To skip tags

```
     private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0) {
                switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
```

The Log

```
05-14 07:03:25.214: I/title is....(2212): day1
05-14 07:03:25.214: I/creation date i....(2212): 1397502000000
05-14 07:03:25.214: I/picture is....(2212): BASE64EncodedStringOfImage
05-14 07:03:25.214: I/comment id is....(2212): 1
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/username is....(2212): sana
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/text is....(2212): i loved that pic
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/comment is....(2212): 1398264140000
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/like id is....(2212): 4
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/username is....(2212): sana
05-14 07:03:25.224: I/liketime is....(2212): 1398250919000
```

More information read

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2217

Answer (score 0):

instead of providing you with a temp way to achieve your case, just have a look at the [DOM parser](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp) and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) and they will give you a general way to parse XML in Android or Java at all

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to parse with JAXB parser?

JAXB is a java parser for XMLs and makes your life really simple when you need to parse XMLs.

Some idea on how to use JAXB is in my blog [here](http://arnabbhagabati.blogspot.in/2013/01/java-snippets.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Cruisoring/EasyXML provides a means to parse XML to Maps, for example.

```
@Test
public void testDocument_mapOf() {

    URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResource("books.xml");

    Document doc = EasySAXParser.parse(url);

    List<? extends Map<String, String>> maps = doc.mapOf("book");

    System.out.println(maps.get(0));

    System.out.println(maps.get(1));
}
```

The result is 12 Map for the 12 books, for the first two XML  elements shown below:

```
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
<!--       <price>44.95</price> -->
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
```

The corresponding first two Map are printed out:

```
{author=Gambardella, Matthew, genre=Computer, description=An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML., id=bk101, title=XML Developer's Guide, publish_date=2000-10-01}
{author=Ralls, Kim, price=5.95, genre=Fantasy, description=A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world., id=bk102, title=Midnight Rain, publish_date=2000-12-16}
```